# accept and decline button in one form

Tags: php, laravel

i've been stuck here i  hours and now i don't know what to do. i have 2 buttons. Accept and Decline. i want to change a foreign key value whenever i clicked those.

this is in my blade

```
<table class="col-5 table table-bordered ml-3 mr-3">
                    <tbody>

                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                              <th colspan="2">RENT REQUEST CARD</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Borrower's Name:</small></p></td>
                            <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->borrowers_name }}</h6></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Email:</small></p></td>
                            <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->email }}</h6></td>              
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Contact number:</small></p></td>
                            <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->contact_number }}</h6></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Date of Return:</small></p></td>
                            <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->return_date }}</h6></td>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Request Status:</small></p></td>
                                <td>
                                    <h5 class="text-danger"><em>{{ $borrower_request->requestStatus->request_status }}</em></h5>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="text-right">

                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>

                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Decline</buttonz>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

i want to change the value of the Request Status. should i put the form on the request status only or in the whole table?

and then here's in mu controller

```
 public function getRequestsId(Request $request, $id)
{
    $borrowersrequest = BorrowerRequest::find($id);
    $requeststatus = RequestStatus::all();

    return view('/borrowsmanager');
}


public function changeStatus(Request $request, $id)
{
    $borrowersrequest = BorrowerRequest::find($id);

    $borrowersrequest->request_status_id = 2;
    $borrowersrequest->save();

    return redirect('/borrowsmanager');
}
```

and then i am thinking how can i make the accept buttons throw value="2" and decline button value="3" if they are on the same form? should split then in 2 different function or maybe in 1? :(

Answer (score 1):

Change your buttons to `input`

```
<input type="submit" name="accept" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept" />

<input type="submit" name="decline" class="btn btn-danger" value="Decline" />
```

Next in `$request` check for existence of `accept` or `decline` property:

```
// Something like
$borrowersrequest->request_status_id = isset($request->accept) ? 2 : 3;
$borrowersrequest->save();
```

If you submit form via ajax - `input type="submit"` will not be passed to server. You'll have to change your js-script (if any) and pass some flag according to pressed button.